If $G$ contains no subdivision of $K_n$ for a given $n$, then $G+uv$ contains at most one subdivision of $K_n$.
Given a graph $G = (V, E)$ and an edge $uv\in V^2 - E$, the graph $G+uv$ might have arbitrarily many more cycles than $G$, created by the new edge. However, if $G$ had no cycles to begin with, then $G+uv$ have at most one cycle. This is an interesting property.
You cannot change the word cycle for anything you want in this statement. For instance, if $G$ have no odd cycles, $G+uv$ might still have many odd cycles. Now I would like to know for which classes of graphs the property hold.
Of course that is too generic of a statement, so here is my particular case of interest:

Conjecture. If $G$ contains no subdivision of $K_n$ for a given $n$, then $G+uv$ contains at most one subdivision of $K_n$.

Of course, the case $n=3$ is the initial statement and for $n\le 2$ the statement is trivial.
I have a feeling this must be true, but no luck proving it. Furthermore, I actually believe we could change $K_n$ for any given graph $H$, that is, if $G$ contains no subdivision of $H$, then $G+uv$ contains at most one. I don't know how much harder this would be to prove.

I do not think that is true. For $n \geq 4$, take 2 $K_n$ and identify 2 pairs of vertices, then remove that edge. Then, there is no way to un-subdivide this graph as each vertex degree $ \geq 3$. Adding in that edge gives us 2 $K_n$. $\quad$ I might be tripping up on the subdivision part, so can you review?

@CalvinLin the graph you described does contain a subgraph which is a subdivision of $K_n$. I'm not requiring the graph itself to be a subdivision.

Take a $K_n$ for $n\ge 4$; subdivide one of its edges into a path $(x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3)$ (where $x_0$ and $x_3$ are vertices of the $K_n$), and then add a new vertex $x_2'$ also adjacent to $x_1$ and $x_3$. For $n \ge 4$, this graph has exactly two subdivisions of $K_n$: the original one, and one using $x_2'$ instead of $x_2$. However, both of them are destroyed if we delete edge $x_0x_1$.
So if we put edge $x_0 x_1$ back in after deletion, we go from no subdivisions to two.
(For $n \le 3$, the structure we added between $x_0$ and $x_3$ has subdivisions of $K_n$ all of its own, which is why this only starts working for $n\ge 4$.)
